# Zip Directory Entry (Filesystem API )

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, html5-filesystem

I have a directory entry (filesystem api). How could I zip it? I would then be  giving it to a save dialog, and would not need to keep it myself.

Answer (score 1):

I think your best bet would be to find a library that does this.  This looks like a good one:

https://stuk.github.io/jszip/

The site has straightforward directions on use.

Comment: Yes, I found that but the setup seems very confusing.

Comment: I changed the link.  This one look like all you have to do is include a file.

Comment: yeah, "jszip" is better than "zipjs". you need to iterate the folders and zip.add() all the files.